Cloudflared Tunnel Installation in Ubuntu 24.04.1 Crashes
I'm installing a cloudflared service in a Ubuntu 24.04.1 machine using a script generated by Cloudflared during a tunnel create action. The comand begins, but lock and do not ends. Some suggestion?
Thanks,
Roberto

Please either add information what type of script it is and what the script is doing in particular or contact the creator of the script. By the information provided so far, it is next to impossible to provide any help.
